# Conditional probability question with removing balls from an urn without replacement.

Tags: probability

Yet another question on my online classes homework that I missed. It doesn't explain how the answer is obtained.

The question:

An urn contains 7 orange balls and 5 blue balls. Two balls are selected at random without replacement. If at least one of them is orange, what is the probability that the other ball is also orange?

The given answer is .375.

So, I'm looking for P(A|B), B is the event that one of them is orange, and A is the event that the other one is also orange.
For P(B), I did P(B$^c$) (none of them are orange, which means they are both blue), which would be (5/12) * (4/11), or .1515. P(B) is 1 - P(B$^c$), so P(B) =.8585.

This is where I get stuck. P(A|B) = P(A $\bigcap$ B) / P(B). But I can't figure out how to find P(A $\bigcap$ B).

Answer (score 1):

In the same way as you calculated for the blue ones you get $$P(A \cap B)= \frac{7}{12} \cdot \frac{6}{11}$$
Which gives you the answer after plugging it into the formula you have.

Comment: Unless I'm calculatoring wrong (which is quite possible), the end equation gives .37058, which isn't .375.

Comment: Use the exact value of $P(B)$, not the approximate one that you typed in the question.

Comment: Welp, I'm dumb. Thank you. Turns out I was doing it all right from the beginning then and just couldn't properly put in values. Thank you!

Comment: @SloanTheSloth luckily sometimes the mistake is that easy